# Error in Connecting Datomic Database

Tags: java, datomic

My datomic database has been hosted on amazon aws server. i have its correct uri and
I am using Peer class to connect datomic database, please find the code below

```
Peer.connect(uri)
```

but i am getting below error on console

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.transform.JsonErrorUnmarshaller: method <init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V not found
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ProvisionedThroughputExceededExceptionUnmarshaller.<init>(ProvisionedThroughputExceededExceptionUnmarshaller.java:26)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.init(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:374)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.<init>(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:306)
    at datomic.ddb$client.invoke(ddb.clj:14)
```

the dependency i am using is

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.datomic</groupId>
            <artifactId>datomic-pro</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5153</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.89</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am not getting why this issue is happening. is this any dependency issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Datomic version `0.9.5153` is quite old at this point (it was released in early 2015), and used AWS SDK version `1.8.11`, so I suspect you're hitting a dependency version mismatch there.

There have been several critical updates to Datomic since that release, so I'd encourage you to move to the latest release (`0.9.5561.62`) if at all possible.

-Marshall

Comment: Thanks Marshall .. i will check it and let you know if that work